# iframe cross domain onClick

Tags: jquery, youtube, onclick

I have a youtube video in my website embeded in an iframe. I want to find out how many clicks to that video from my website (not the total views). I could not find an onClick (or similar) event for an iframe and the jquery bind event method only works for the iframe in same domain. Please help.

Comment: You know that in the youtube analytics it will actually show you the number of hits from each individual website that hits it? This seems redundant.

Comment: I do not own that video. My actual issue is to put all those clicks in the google analytics.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. If you want to track clicks, I suppose you could have some sort of thumbnail with a play button, which records the click and then loads the iFrame onto the page then.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting your document domain to youtube.com in javascript document ready:

```
document.domain = "youtube.com";
```

Never tried it with an external site, but at least that works on different intranet sites.